# PyGTK TreeColumns all exact duplicates

Tags: python, pygtk, gtktreeview

I wrote a simple PyGTK script to show some basic process information in a TreeView:

```
import gtk
import os
import pwd
import grp

class ProcParser:
    """
    Parses the status file of a particular process
    """
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.lines = map(lambda x: x[:-1], open(fname).readlines())

    def get_by_val(self, val):
        for line in self.lines:
            if line.startswith(val):
                return line.split()
        return []

class Proc:
    """
    A process in the /proc filesystem

    This class uses a ProcParser to determine it's own information
    """
    def __init__(self, pid):
        self.pid = int(pid)
        self.parser = ProcParser("/proc/{0}/status".format(self.pid))
        self._from_file()

    def _from_file(self):
        self.uid = self.parser.get_by_val("Uid")[1]
        self.gid = self.parser.get_by_val("Gid")[1]
        self.name = self.parser.get_by_val("Name")[1]
        self.user = pwd.getpwuid(int(self.uid)).pw_name
        self.group = grp.getgrgid(int(self.gid)).gr_name

class ProcTree:
    "A tree that displays all running processes"
    def __init__(self):
        self.view = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.store = gtk.ListStore(str, int, str, str)
        self.tree = gtk.TreeView(self.store)
        self.cells = [
            gtk.CellRendererText(),
            gtk.CellRendererText(),
            gtk.CellRendererText(),
            gtk.CellRendererText()
        ]
        self.tvcols = [
            gtk.TreeViewColumn("Name"),
            gtk.TreeViewColumn("Pid"),
            gtk.TreeViewColumn("User"),
            gtk.TreeViewColumn("Group")
        ]

    def __call__(self):
        return self.view

    def config(self):
        for col, cell in zip(self.tvcols, self.cells):
            col.pack_start(cell, True)
            col.add_attribute(cell, "text", 0)
            self.tree.append_column(col)
        self._update_store()
        self.view.add_with_viewport(self.tree)

    def show(self):
        self.tree.show()
        self.view.show()

    def _update_store(self):
        self.store.clear()
        for item in os.listdir("/proc"):
            try: pwid = int(item)
            except: continue
            pr = Proc(pwid)
            self.store.append((pr.name, int(pr.pid), pr.user, pr.group))

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.proctree = ProcTree()

    def config(self):
        self.proctree.config()
        self.window.add(self.proctree())
        self.window.set_title("Process Viewer")

    def show(self):
        self.proctree.show()
        self.window.show()

    def run(self):
        self.config()
        self.show()

win = Window()
win.run()
gtk.main()
```

My issue is that all of the columns' values are the same.

Notes:

1. Apparently this is correlated with the first column (ie If I change the first column's data, then that's what all of the other data become)

(Will add more as suggestions are posted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for append on treview you should do

```
    rendererText = gtk.CellRendererText()
    tvcols = ["Name", "Pid", "User", "Group"]

    for num, name in enumerate(tvcols):
        column_name = gtk.TreeViewColumn(name ,rendererText, text=num)
        self.tree.append_column(column_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me enumerate, by the way. I've always used
"for val, index in (iterable, range(len(iterable)):"