# PyGTK - Adding Rows to gtk.TreeStore

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

After following the official tutorial here: [tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-TreeViewWidget.html)

I'm still having issues adding rows/creating a TreeIter object. Here's what my code looks like:

```
    builder = gtk.Builder()
    self.treeview = builder.get_object("treeview")
    self.treestore = gtk.TreeStore(str)

    self.treeview.set_model(self.treestore)

    self.id = gtk.TreeViewColumn('ID')
    self.type = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Type")
    self.readName = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Filename")
    self.set = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Set")

    self.treeview.append_column(self.id)
    self.treeview.append_column(self.readName)
    self.treeview.append_column(self.type)
    self.treeview.append_column(self.set)

    self.cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
    self.cell1 = gtk.CellRendererText()
    self.cell2 = gtk.CellRendererText()
    self.cell3 = gtk.CellRendererText()

    self.id.pack_start(self.cell, True)
    self.readName.pack_start(self.cell1, True)
    self.type.pack_start(self.cell2, True)
    self.set.pack_start(self.cell3, True)

    self.id.add_attribute(self.cell, 'text', 0)
    self.readName.add_attribute(self.cell1, 'text', 1)
    self.type.add_attribute(self.cell2, 'text', 2)
    self.set.add_attribute(self.cell3, 'text', 3)

    self.treeview.set_reorderable(True)

    self.readListVP.add(self.treeview)

    iter = self.treestore.get_iter(self.treestore.get_path(iter)) #here's where my problem lies
    self.treestore.set_value(None, 0, self.fileCountStr)
    self.treestore.set_value(None, 1, "paired-end")
    self.treestore.set_value(None, 2, self.file)
    self.treestore.set_value(None, 3, self.readSetStr)
```

Comment: Okay, you've put a comment where your problem lies, but *what exactly is your problem*? And where's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spot a number of general problems with the code as well:

1. You're creating too many `CellRenderer`'s! Use just one for the whole table.
2. Don't use the `Builder()`! It's just stupidly overcomplicating things.
3. You're not adding columns the most efficent way.

Look into the question [I've already asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505171/pygtk-treecolumns-all-exact-duplicates)